# Exporting to txt file not allowing more than 255 characters

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Below is the script that i have used which shows that i have used BCP process and some shell script to generate the extracts. we need to take the data from sql table and dump as it is in table to flat file. So these can be used to load in hive tables and qlick apps for users to have a look at the data.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GenerateEAPExtracts] @tblName NVARCHAR(MAX), @filePath VARCHAR(255)
As
BEGIN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
Drop table #Temp1
END


--DECLARE @tblName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'BMI.BMI_Invites'
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @tbl varchar(100)
DECLARE @DBName varchar(100)

SET @tbl= Replace(@tblname,(Left(@tblname,(LEN(@tblname)-(charindex('.',reverse(@tblname))-1)))),'');
SET @SchemaName= SUBSTRING(@tblName,1,LEN(Left(@tblname,(LEN(@tblname)-(charindex('.',reverse(@tblname))-1))))-1);


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @ColConvert NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @ColName1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @ColName2 NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @Dt NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @I INT=1, @COUNT INT;


Create table #Temp1(
               ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
               [DBName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
               [TableName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
               [Attributes] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
               [DataType] [nvarchar](MAX) NULL,
               [TceMdf_Dt] [date] NULL
)

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #Temp1 select TABLE_CATALOG as [DBName],
                              Table_Name as [TableName],
                              Column_name as [Attributes],
                              DATA_TYPE as [DataType],
                              getdate() as [TceMdf_Dt]                            
from Information_schema.columns where Table_Schema ='''+ @SchemaName +''' AND  table_name = '''+@tbl+''''
print @SQL
--EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)


SELECT @SQL1='Select @totCnt= count(1) FROM Information_schema.columns where Table_Schema ='''+ @SchemaName +''' AND  table_name = '''+@tbl+''''
print @SQL1
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL1, N'@totCnt int OUTPUT', @totCnt=@COUNT OUTPUT


WHILE @I <= @COUNT
BEGIN

               SELECT @ColName = Attributes FROM #Temp1 WHERE ID = @I AND [TableName]=@tbl; 

               SELECT @DBName = DBName FROM #Temp1 WHERE ID = @I AND [TableName]=@tbl;

              SELECT @Dt= DataType FROM #Temp1 WHERE ID = @I AND [TableName]=@tbl AND [Attributes]=@ColName

              IF @Dt ='Date' or @Dt='Datetime' or @Dt='Decimal' or @Dt='Int' or @Dt='Float' or @Dt='datetime2' or @Dt='Numeric' or @Dt='Real' or @Dt='bit' or @Dt='tinyint'
              BEGIN
              SET @ColConvert='convert(varchar(25),['+@ColName+'],120)'
              --EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColConvert

               SET @ColName2  = @ColName2 + ',' + @ColConvert 
               --EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColName2
              END

              ELSE

              BEGIN
               SET @ColName2  = @ColName2 + ',' + '['+@ColName+']'
               --EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColName2

              END

               SET @ColName1  = @ColName1 +''''+''''+','+''''+''''+ @ColName
               --EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColName1


               SET @I=@I+1;

END

SET @ColName1=RIGHT(@ColName1, LEN(@ColName1) - 3) + ''''''

SET @ColName2=LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@ColName2, LEN(@ColName2) - 1)))

--print @ColName1
--print @ColName2

--DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCommand1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlCommand2 VARCHAR(MAX)



 DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)='(SELECT MaxCDate from '+@DBName+'.config.EAP_Extracts where TableName= '''''+ @tbl +''''')'
 print @qry
 --exec(@qry)

--SET    @filePath = 'C:\'
SET    @fileName = @tbl + '_' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + '.csv'


set  @sqlCommand = 'SQLCMD.EXE -S LocalHost -d TCE_WW -E -h -1 -s"|" -W -Q "set nocount on;SELECT ' +@ColName1+ ' ; Select ' +@ColName2+ ' FROM '+@DBName+'.' +@tblName+ ''
print(@sqlCommand)
set  @sqlCommand1 =' where TceMdf_Dt > '+ @qry +'' 
set  @sqlCommand2 ='" -o "'+@filePath+@fileName+'" -f 65001'



--declare @chkQry varchar(max) = @sqlCommand+@sqlCommand1+@sqlCommand2
--print(@chkQry)
Update config.EAP_Extracts Set [SqlMaxQuery]=@sqlCommand+@sqlCommand1+@sqlCommand2 where TableName=''+@tbl+''


declare  @CommandString varchar(max)= (select distinct 'EXEC  xp_cmdshell '+''''+[SqlMaxQuery]+'''' from config.EAP_Extracts where TableName=''+@tbl+'')
--declare  @CommandString varchar(max)= 'EXEC  xp_cmdshell ' + ''''+@chkQry+'''' 

print @CommandString
EXEC (@CommandString)


 declare @SQLQuery varchar(max)='Update '+@DBName+'.config.EAP_Extracts Set MaxCDate=(Select  Max(TceMdf_Dt) from '+ @tblName+') where TableName='''+@tbl+''''
 --EXEC  xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''update_action'',''UserName'',''lastupdate'',''Quote_Num'',''Region'',''ExternalDataReference'',''TceLd_Dt'',''TceMdf_Dt'',''Record_Status'' ; Select LTRIM(RTRIM[update_action]),LTRIM(RTRIM[UserName]),LTRIM(RTRIM[lastupdate]),LTRIM(RTRIM[Quote_Num]),LTRIM(RTRIM[Region]),LTRIM(RTRIM[ExternalDataReference]),convert(varchar(25),LTRIM(RTRIM[TceLd_Dt]),120),convert(varchar(25),LTRIM(RTRIM[TceMdf_Dt]),120),LTRIM(RTRIM[Record_Status]) FROM TCE_WW.BMI.BMI_Invites where TceMdf_Dt > (SELECT MaxCDate from TCE_WW.config.EAP_Extracts where TableName= 'BMI_Invites')" queryout "C:\BMI_Invites_20190722.txt" -T -c -q -y 0 -t"|"'

exec (@SQLQuery)
 print(@SQLQuery)



Drop table #Temp1


END
```

Comment: You mentioned `BCP` but your are using `SQLCMD`. These are different utilities. Try using BCP instead for export.

Comment: I am using the BCP process to sql cmd to extract from table to txt format. i am trying to share the BCP query but unable to put it in this task box.   Can you let me how can i share you the BCP commends that i am using, as i am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: I think what you want is something like `SET  @bcpCommand ='BCP.EXE "SELECT ''' +@ColName1 + ''' UNION ALL SELECT ' + @ColName2 + ' FROM ' + @DBName + '..' + @tblName + '" queryout "C:\temp\yourfile.txt" -c -t"|" -T';`

Comment: Thanks Dan.... i am using the same in the queryout as  "xp_cmdshell"... but still its getting trimmed at 256 characters... I tried -y 0 and i was able to get more than 256 characters but i got another issue after adding this. i see a lot of spaces in between each column

Comment: I ran the exact bcp command from my comment and text is not truncated. `-y` is not a bcp argument, AFAIK. How are you determining the text is truncated?

Comment: I have a column by name Composite_key (which is a combination of multiple columns) where when i check the table i see the length of the character is more thatn 255 and checked the max len for this column it was 5025. After extracting the data to txt and exported to excel and followed the same process to check the length. the length is 255. So i cross checked some of the records in txt file and the complete data is not taking

Comment: i am not sure how i can share you the complete script.. so you can help me where i have gone wrong.

Comment: Also, the standard format that i need to generate the flat file is in UTF8

Comment: Edit your question to add a simplified script that reproduces the problem. That would be like `CREATE TABLE YourTable(Composite_key varchar(5025));INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES(REPLICATE('X',5025));` followed by the rest of the export script. Run it before posting to make sure it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi Dan, i have posted the complete script which i am using to generate the extracts. please do have a look and do let me know what is that i am missing in the script for truncating the characters more than 256.        Please note that we have to use UTF8 as this is the standard process to provide extracts in the company

Comment: we are using this script as a loop to generate 33 tables extracts and provdied the variable of the file path and file name in SSIS package.

Comment: You've seriously got everything here. `SQLCMD`, `BCP`, `xp_cmdshell`, `SSIS`. All to generate a flat file. This is way overcomplicated and  this is probably contributed to your issue

Comment: I know... this was a new project that i took over 15 days back before my peer left the job.